# Cygwin / Upgrade from Windows 7 to Windows 10 / Unknown+User and Unknown+Group

Tags: cygwin

I upgraded from Windows 7 to 10 and I am not able to use a tar command in Cygwin. I get an error: Permission denied. When I look at the output of ls -la I can see that all the files and folders belong to Unknown+User and Unknown+Group and as far as I imagine this is causing the problem that I have. What would be the safest and the best way of fixing this? I am working on a backup data and if something goes wrong I can lose a year and a half of all day / week work. I am looking for something 100% good and correct.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, don't panic. This looks like a problem with the translation of numeric ids to their display names. To check this, use `ls -lan`. The `-n` option will display user and group numeric ids instead of the display names.

On the cygwin site at https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net.html you will find the user guide. Issues relating to mapping windows accounts to posix accounts is documented at https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/ntsec.html in Chapter 3.

This process is a lot easier and automatic than it used to be. Just be sure to make backup copies of any file you delete or edit.